# Not able to mock createQueryBuilder functions typeorm nestjs jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I am trying to write unit test cases for my service file. There is a function linkDevice that joins 2 tables user and device and returns the object. I check if the device is already assigned to the user or not. If it is assigned I throw a BadRequestExcpetion and if not I add it to the user.

I tried adding a mockResolvedValue to the where function but it gave the following error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValue' of undefined

      129 |       new BadRequestException(),
      130 |     );
    > 131 |     profileRepository.createQueryBuilder.where.mockResolvedValue();
          |                                                ^
      132 |     const result = await service.linkDevice(device, 2);
      133 |     console.log(result);
      134 |     expect(service.linkDevice).toHaveBeenCalledWith(device, 2);
```

service.spec.ts

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ProfileService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Profile),
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
            save: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn(),
            createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(() => ({
              where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
              setParameter: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
              leftJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
              getOne: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            })),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<ProfileService>(ProfileService);
    profileRepository = module.get(getRepositoryToken(Profile));
  });

 it('should throw error if device is already linked to profile', async () => {
    profileRepository.createQueryBuilder.mockResolvedValue(
      new BadRequestException(),
    );
    const result = await service.linkDevice(device, 2);
    console.log(result);
    expect(service.linkDevice).toHaveBeenCalledWith(device, 2);
  });
```

Error

```
  TypeError: this.profileRepository.createQueryBuilder(...).where is not a function

      55 |     const user = await this.profileRepository
      56 |       .createQueryBuilder('profile')
    > 57 |       .where('profile.id = :id')
         |        ^
      58 |       .setParameter('id', userId)
      59 |       .leftJoinAndSelect('profile.device', 'device')
      60 |       .getOne();

      at ProfileService.linkDevice (../src/modules/profile/profile.service.ts:57:8)
      at Object.<anonymous> (profile.service.spec.ts:131:34)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to throw the error, you should use `mockRejectedValue` instead of `mockResolvedValue`. You also probably want to use `mockRejectedValueOnce` specificially, otherwise you're overriding the mock you set up from before. Otherwise your mock setup looks fine.

Comment: In the case where I want to mock an actual value a result how can I do that?

Comment: use `mockResolvedValueOnce` instead of `mockRejectedValueOnce`